# Bootstrap Dropdown expands but does not contain any Items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My dropdown opens up but it shows an empty menu and does not have the items I've added. Here's a picture:

[image]

However my dropdown contains items:

```
    <div class="btn-group">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               Choose Theme <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li>Blue</li>
               <li>Purple</li>
               <li>Green</li>
               <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
```

This is my head:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () { $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); }); </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Am I missing something? Why does this happen?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0e82jsms/ working fine for me,have any javascript errord?

Comment: None at all. Actually I've used the same code in a modal and it works fine. I've put it in a table inside a <tr><td> in this scenario. Is this the issue? Doesn't it work inside tables? I've actually taken it out and it stil doesnt work @Shijin

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with your current code.,may be some other javascript conflicts there

Comment: Can you check your source code using firebug to see what you have in that dropdown of styles?

Comment: I've just created a plunker with your code and it's working properly. http://plnkr.co/edit/ZgU36TdqOrL3TVL7S0J4?p=preview

Comment: *I've put it in a table inside a <tr><td> in this scenario.* Please post the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bootstrap you dont need

`<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () { $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); }); </script>`

Try this with out what you have for calling the script and you will see it works.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>

<body>


        <!--Default buttons with dropdown menu-->
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--Primary buttons with dropdown menu-->



</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be js error,add this link below and i tried its works

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```